# How to add a text automatically to an excel cell when a cell or cells are filled?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know this is a long tittle but I really don't know how to put the title to what I am looking for so sorry for that.

Right, basically my question is for the excel spreadsheet. And I will use an example on the cells names such as A1, B2, C3 and so on.

I am trying to make the the cell G2 to automatically be filled with a text such as example "Hello World", only when the cells A2, B2, F2 are typed in (with any text).

I'm hoping someone will be able to help me solving this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an if statement:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),NOT(ISBLANK(B2)),NOT(ISBLANK(F2))),"Hello World","")
```

Test all cells for blank and if all are filled in then give "Hello World".

For your second question (you should start another question): 
Put this code in the Sheet code; not in a module and not in the Workbook.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not VBA.IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        If target.address = "$E$1" Then
            Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Could I ask another question? Is there a way when you type into the cells to UPPER CASE the text?

Comment: try =Upper(A2) this will  upper case the text.

Comment: It didn't quite work out.. Basically I the spreadsheet is empty and I wanted to UPPER case as you type in the cell. Is this possible?

Comment: That's a new question: basically you need VBA. You would need to handle the Worksheet_Change event and set the text to upper case. Best wishes.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a macro code I could use for this function?

Comment: If this is helpful, please click the check mark on the left to accept as answer and also click the up button to upvote.

Comment: Hello D_Bester I tried to vote this answer but it looks like my reputation isn't that high enough to vote... And where do I put this code? Where is the Sheet code please?

Comment: In Excel press keys Alt & F11 to get into code editor.

Comment: Oh yes! Done! How about where I actually put this code? Where is the Sheet code located please?

Comment: On the upper left corner in the Project pane, double click Sheet1

Comment: That will be all cells. What modifications can I do on the code to specify the cells I want to Uppercase please? Sorry to be a pain

Comment: if target.address = "$E$1" then

Comment: Sorry... And where about on the code do I put this line?